# Encoding with little endianness Go lang

Tags: go, encoding, endianness

I am having to work on a web server for work and there are portions of our code written by our chief engineers that I don't understand and am currently trying to decipher. Here is a similar and much simpler version of what is happening within our code base, and I was wondering if anyone could give me a deep explanation of what this is doing step by step.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "encoding/binary"
func main() {
////////////////////////////////// no need to explain anything
    b := []byte{2,3,5,7,11,13} /// within this comment block.
    for _,e := range b {        //
    fmt.Printf("%d ",e)         //
    }                           //
    fmt.Printf("\n")            //
    //////////////////////////////
    length:= binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(b)  /// <<< Why this results in                                                 
                                            /// 117768962 is the question.
    fmt.Printf("customLen=%d\n",int(length))

}
```

Comment: Is the confusion because a `uint32` is only 32 bits, so the `11` and `13` are ignored?

Comment: no, if you you chop off the 11 and 13 its still going to give you 117768962, my biggest question here is wondering what that new number "represents"

Comment: yes, you can add as many extra values as you want, but you can only decode 32 bits into a 32 bit value. The `LittleEndian.Uint32` function is only really 1 line of code: https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go#L62

Comment: It represents the first 4 bytes (size of a `uint32`) as a uint32. All of the stdlib code is available to view, and it's even linked from the documentation, if you're curious to know what any stdlib function does step by step.

Comment: @smokums, The fact that you're decoding the value into something named "length" means that this is probably extracted from some code to parse a larger binary format. Perhaps supplying the context for what you're doing here would help guide someone to an answer. As it is, this is not much different than asking why `0x07050302` is the same as `117768962`, the former is just a different representation or encoding the latter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When we write numbers in English, we write them in big-endian base-10 representation. For example the number "4567" is understood to mean `4*10^3 + 5*10^2 + 6*10^1 + 7*10^0`. This is **base-10** because each written digit differs in significance by a factor of 10 from adjacent digits, and it is **big-endian** because the first written digit is associated with the biggest power of 10.

The same number 4567 could be written in little-endian base-10 as "7654", which in little-endian representation would mean `7*10^0 + 6*10^1 + 5*10^2 + 4*10^3`, numerically the same as in the previous paragraph. This is **little-endian** because the first written digit is associated with the littlest power of 10.

The [`binary.LittleEndian.Uint32`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder) function receives a slice of bytes and reads out of it a 32-bit unsigned integer represented in **little-endian base-256**.

So if the base-256 digits in the input slice `b` are `2,3,5,7` as they are in your code, the little-endian base-256 interpretation of those bytes is `2*256^0 + 3*256^1 + 5*256^2 + 7*256^3`. The same number written in big-endian base-10 (which is what `fmt.Printf` will show you) is "117768962".

Comment: You sir are a godsend. This is EXACTLY the response I was looking for. I was completely unaware that it was represented in base 256. I couldnt find that anywhere in the Go API.